# What database should I use for mining pool for blockchain?

Tags: mysql, redis, blockchain, mining

I am creating a mining pool (blockchain thing). The thing is I decided to use the plugin https://github.com/zone117x/node-open-mining-portal which is written in node.js and using redis database for saving shares,payments and things like that. My questions are the following?

**1) Should I use redis database or transfer code to mysql?**

My assumption is the following: Redis is supper fast, but I am worried about data loss. as you know , it saved information in memory first,then transfers that information to the disk. What if data is lost during this moment? I googled and there're some ways to minimize the chance of losing data such as RDB AND AOF. Will these 2 help me to almost minimize chance of losing data to 0.001% ? If I use mysql, It's much better because of acid transactions but it'll be slow because if I have 100,000 miners, for each of their share, i have to make 1 query to save data in mysql, and It seems for 100,000 miners there is a chance of saving 300,000 records in 1-2 seconds. That seems bad. On the another other hand, Mysql seems better for flexibility ,it will be easier to fetch data depending on any criterium.

I need your advice . Just give me little advice. Thank you in advance .

Comment: why don't use both? create a worker that takes data from redis and insert to mysql db...

Comment: I'm not an expert in this field - And I think this question is off topic here. But you might want to have a look at *TokuDB engine*.

Comment: why would I need both? from your poinf of view, taking data from redis to mysql is a guaranteed way of not losing data? then which one should I use to show my users their information?

Comment: using them in a pair wouldn't help with anything

Comment: Are you not satisfied with the answer? Maybe consider accepting it.

Comment: How would I be satisfied? I said redis or mysql. You say something different at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Aerospike](https://www.aerospike.com/products/aerospike-database-platform/) is both fast and strongly consistent. Also it much easily scales than Redis.